# Menus overlapping

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having a big issue with a website - I really hope you can help me out.

https://www.hillcrestatc.com/mood-disorders/

There is a main menu and submenu showing on such a page.

When one hovers over the main menu on this page and then tries to select a suboption, the dropdown disappears and acts as if they want something from the secondary menu.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Links to active pages aren't very helpful. If you are trying to fix things, it is hard for us to tell if your code is changing. Try and replicate the issue with as little code as possible. For a start, take out everything besides the Menu, for all of HTML, CSS and Javascript. Also what happens if you show the dropdown as the initial state?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your website on vivaldi (chromium) and it shows that the sub menus of the first top menu can't be reached. I used the debugger, toyed around and found the solution: z-indexes

The thing is the secondary menu has a z-index:1 !important and the top one doesn't, so it gets kind of mixed (sorry I can't really "explain" it clearly).

Here are two lines of code you can try in your css, and also try to remove this one while you're at it, otherwise it won't work:

At line 33:

```
.fusion-secondary-main-menu {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    z-index: 1!important; /*delete this line here*/
}
```

Add these two lines:

```
.fusion-header{position:relative;z-index:1;}
.fusion-secondary-main-menu{position:relative;z-index:0;}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hello!
I checked the website 2 minutes ago on chrome,vivaldi and firefox and the menu is fine now for me. Have you tried clearing your browser's cache? Maybe it's still storing the previous version of the css.

You can try ctrl+F5 on the page, or clear the cache of your browser directly.

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you so so much!